# Neo4j finding shortest paths from all nodes, between all nodes

Tags: database, neo4j

this is probably straightforward to most people here but I'm very new to neo4j. I am trying to do this problem where I need to match all genres in this movie database with all other genres and find the shortest path. I am given this skeleton of code:

```
   match (g:Genre)
   with g.genre as genre1
      YOUR CODE GOES HERE
   return distinct genre1, g2.genre as genre2, length(path)/2 as length
   order by length desc, genre1, genre2;
```

It seems to imply all the code I need to write should go in that area, but I don't know what I need to put there? Do I need to put another match in there? All I really know is how do find the shortes path from one node to all the others:

```
match path = allshortestpaths( 
        (g1:GENRE{name:"Thriller"})-[Genre_in*]-(g2:GENRE)
    )
```

but not from all nodes to all other nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that skeleton code is a bit weird anyhow. Why would you want to extract the
`genre` property when you need to find shortest paths between nodes.

There are a couple of approaches. I would use the following:

```
// Match all combination of genres
match (g1:Genre), (g2:Genre)
// remove duplicates
WHERE id(g1) < id(g2)
// find shortest path
MATCH path=((g1)-[*]-(g2))
// return results
RETURN g1.genre AS genre1, g2.genre AS genre2, length(path) AS length
ORDER BY length DESC, genre1, genre2
```

Why does the skeleton code divide the path by 2 I have no idea.